# Optimize Cursor with Linked Server - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a cursor using a linked server, it is too long to process, would please me provide tips to optimize. Imagine that this top 20 takes 3 minutes. The stored procedures that run are simple updates.

Thanks in advance

PD: I plan to use this cursor on a job

```
Use MMProdat
go
Declare @query nvarchar(MAX)
declare @id varchar(100)
declare @name varchar(100)
declare @prequery varchar(800)
declare @prequery2 varchar(800)
declare @prequery3 varchar(800)
select @prequery = 'declare @p3 bit' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'set @p3 = NULL' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
select @prequery2 = 'declare @p4 int' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'set @p4 = 0' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'declare @p5 int' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'set @p5 = 0' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'declare @p6 int' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'set @p6 = 0' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
select @prequery3 = 'declare @p5 int' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'set @p5 = 0' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'declare @p6 int' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'set @p6 = 0' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'declare @p7 int' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'set @p7 = 0' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE cursorQuery CURSOR FOR
    select top 20 Id, Query, Name from [10.1.13.202].MMProdatHA.dbo.OPContacts where exeproc = 0 order by tmstmp
            OPEN cursorQuery
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursorQuery INTO @id, @query, @name
            WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
            BEGIN
                IF ( @name = 'OuPNeedsContactReset')
                begin

                        select @query = @prequery + @query + ', @p3 OUTPUT'
                        print @query
                        EXECUTE sp_executesql @query 
                        update [10.1.13.202].MMProdatHA.dbo.OPContacts set ExeProc = 1 where Id = @id
                end
                ELSE IF ( @name = 'OuPCountProcessContacts')
                begin

                        select @query = @prequery2 + @query + ',@p4 output,@p5 output,@p6 output'
                        print @query
                        EXECUTE sp_executesql @query 
                        update [10.1.13.202].MMProdatHA.dbo.OPContacts set ExeProc = 1 where Id = @id
                end
                ELSE IF ( @name = 'OuPCountBatchContacts')
                begin

                        select @query = @prequery3 + @query + ',@p5 output,@p6 output,@p7 output'
                        print @query
                        EXECUTE sp_executesql @query 
                        update [10.1.13.202].MMProdatHA.dbo.OPContacts set ExeProc = 1 where Id = @id
                end
                else
                begin
                        EXECUTE sp_executesql @query 
                        update [10.1.13.202].MMProdatHA.dbo.OPContacts set ExeProc = 1 where Id = @id
                end



            FETCH NEXT FROM cursorQuery INTO @id, @query, @name
            END
            CLOSE cursorQuery
            DEALLOCATE cursorQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Linked Server, you retrieve all data from the remote table and the Condition clause will be execute on your MSSQL and not on the Remote MSSQL.
To avoid from bringing all table data from the remote server you need to filter it on the remote server.
one way of doing it is to create table function on the remote MSSQL that will receive the value you want to filter .
and then instead of call the  the [10.1.13.202].MMProdatHA.dbo.OPContacts with filter condition 
you will call [10.1.13.202].MMProdatHA.dbo.fn_OPContacts(@exeproc).

Thanks,
Mano